# How to get integer labels from MNIST examples after specifying one_hot=True?

Tags: python, tensorflow, mnist, one-hot-encoding

I have been attempting [this tutorial on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wuo4JdG3SvU) (explination of .cls and .labels at [1m31s](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wuo4JdG3SvU#t=1m31s)) which is just a simple MNIST classifier model. But I was unable to complete it due to an apparently missing function in Tensorflow.

```
>>>from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
>>>data = input_data.read_data_sets("data/MNIST", one_hot=True)

>>>one_hot_labels = data.test.labels #mat shape=(num_images X num_classes)
>>>cls_labels = data.test.cls #mat shape=(num_images X 1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/file.py", line 5, in <module>
    cls_labels = data.test.cls
AttributeError: 'DataSet' object has no attribute 'cls'
```

After searching on Google for ".cls" reference in TF, I was unable to find any information pertaining to it.

A dirty example that made things work:

```
>>>data = input_data.read_data_sets("data/MNIST", one_hot=True)
>>>data2 = input_data.read_data_sets("data/MNIST")

>>>one_hot_labels = data.test.labels #mat shape=(num_images X num_classes)
>>>cls_labels = data2.test.labels #mat shape=(num_images X 1)
```

I am using Tensorflow 0.10.0 on Linux and am wondering if the .cls option has been removed?

If so, is there an alternative method for encoding an array of classifier names from an array of one_hot vectors?

Thanks

Comment: I found a workaround using Numpy. When you specify one_hot=True then you can encode it back to an array of integer labels using: np.argmax(data.test.labels, axis=1)

Answer (score 3):

Your labels are in this type of array (one hot) for example :

```
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
```

The number 1. is in the position of the array where tells you which label is.

To get a integer label from this data you have to get the index with:

```
data.test.cls = np.argmax(data.test.labels, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently we use attribute `images` for image data and `labels` for classes(labels). For example,

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("data/MNIST", one_hot=True)
# data
images = mnist.test.images
# label
labels = mnist.test.labels

# without one-hot
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("data/MNIST", one_hot=False)
# original data
images = mnist.test.images.reshape([-1, 28, 28])
print(images.shape)
# label
labels = mnist.test.labels
print(labels)
```

Comment: I noticed the images function, however that is a flattened vector of pixel data and not the integer label corresponding to its one_hot vector. eg: data.test.labels = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0] and data.test.cls = [7]

Comment: Yes, the original `read_data_sets` function transforms MNIST image into one-dimension vector, if you want to get original data, `reshape` the data and you will get it. And if you want to have integer labels, you need to use `one_hot=False` in `read_data_sets` function. I have change code to illustrate them.